# Retrieve a function parameter from probability distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be two sets such as $|\mathcal{A}| = n$ and $|\mathcal{B}| = m$.

Let $f$ be a function such that
\begin{align*}
  f_x \colon \mathcal{A}  &\to \mathcal{B}\\
  a  &\mapsto f_x(a).
\end{align*}

For each $x \in \mathcal{A}$ we a compute the probability distribution of couples $(a,f_x(a))$ noted $D_x$.

Suppose that for a fixed $x$ that is unknow, we run an experiment that returns a set of samples $\mathcal{S} = \{(a,f_x(a))|a \in \mathcal{A}\}$

**Given $\mathcal{S}$ and the probability distributions $D_x$, how to compute the probability $P(X=x)$ ?**

For a single couple (i.e. $|\mathcal{S}| = 1$), the probability $P(X=x|\mathcal{S})$ can be easily computed from all the distributions $D_x$ but how to deal with larger sets?

Comment: Any given set of samples $\mathcal S=\{(a,g(a))\mid a\in\mathcal A\}$ uniquely defines a function $g$, thus $X$ is uniform on the set $\{x\mid f(\ ,x)=g\}$ if this set is nonempty, otherwise $X$ is undefined. No stochasticity here, I am afraid.

Comment: @Did Why $X$ should be uniform on $\{x | f(,x) = g\}$? If $\mathcal{S} = \{(1,2)\}$ and we suppose that $D_1$ indicates that $(1,2)$ occurs with $p=0.3$ while $D_2$ indicates $p=0.01$ so $x$ is more likely to be equal to $1$ than $2$.